# Unity game doesn't detect every click

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a 2d game with a player ( a ball ) that jumps when I touch the screen. I accomplish this with :

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) || Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
    gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity=Vector.up*speed;
    gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
}
```

(The code is in `Update()`) 
There isn't any type of problem in the Editor, but when I debug the game on my Android phone the ball doesn't jump every time I touch the screen and, due to the gravity, it fall down, as if I had not touched. In particular I noticed that the problem is more evident after some minutes of play, or every time I realod the level. I've tried many things but none helped me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But with buttons and normal tap this code works perfectly on my mobile devices. Otherwisehow can i detect this Input on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` does not officially work with touches, however, it sometimes still gets called, which is undocumented behavior and should therefore not be relied on.

If you want to check for a touch you can use:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
```

As a sidenote *(This is not part of the touch input problem you're having)* : Try to add forces to the `rigidbody` instead of setting the `velocity` directly as this might otherwise "break" the physics simulation.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's much better! However after some "replay" ( level reloads ) it is every time more laggy, or anyway less fluid than the first play. Indeed when I close (deleting the game from recent apps ) and open the game the touch detection is perfect again!

Comment: Yes, I've tried to AddForce to the rigidbody before trying the velocity method, but the second method seems to me more efficient. Anyway I'll try to implement the AddForce better.

Comment: If every touch gets recognized but there is only some lag then this is another problem. Do you create lots of new gameobjects that don't get destroyed within your scene?

Comment: In total I have about 20 different obstacles and other 10 gameobject. I destroy it when collide with the bottom of the screen , then I create a new obstacles, so the obstacles in the scene are always 20, The point is why this problem is more evident after some reload? When I reload the level shouldn't it be resetted?

Comment: @rickyxd As I said, this shouldn't have anything to do with the touch input detection. You might want to ask a new question and provide enough information there so that people can figure out what the specific issue is :)

Answer (score 3):

Both `Input.GetMouseButtonDown()` and `Input.GetKeyDown()` are not associated with Mobile Touch input detection. For touch detection, check [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html) reference.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try it but why some touch on mobile are detected with Input.GetMouseButtonDown() ?

Comment: And I noticed that I'm currently using Application.LoadLevel that is deprecated instead of  SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name); could this be one of the problems?

Comment: @rickyxd No. `SceneManager.LoadScene` is not creating that problem.